# Big $\mathscr{O}$ notation - division operation

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, simulation, numerical-calculus

Consider that the following constant $h$ (time-step size) and $p$ as the order of convergence of some numerical method. On a source I read

---

$$\dfrac{\mathscr{O}(h^{p+1})}{\mathscr{O}\left(\frac{h}{2}^{p+1}\right)}=\mathscr{O}\left(h\right)\tag{1}$$

---

Why does the above result hold true? As far as I am concerned, if I remember correctly, it holds true that $$\mathscr{O}\left(\frac{h}{2}^{p+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}^{p+1}\cdot\mathscr{O}\left(h^{p+1}\right)=\mathscr{O}\left(h^{p+1}\right)$$
However, I cannot realize the reason why equation $(1)$ holds true. Could you please help me understand that?

Comment: $h$ and $p$ cannot both be constants - with respect to which one you consider $O$?

Comment: Of course, sorry. I have just edited

Comment: hm.. I finished before see your new edition and comment. Let me little time to adjust my answer also.

Comment: If we are using big-$O$, as usual, to signify simply an upper bound on the size of the function, then *we can never divide by big-$O$*. For example, one might think it should be true that $O(x^6)/O(x^4) = O(x^2)$. However, for $f(x)=x^6$ and $g(x)=x$ it is valid that $f(x)=O(x^6)$ and $g(x)=O(x^4)$ (verify this second statement!), but $f(x)/g(x) = x^5$ is not $O(x^2)$. Moral: dividing by an upper bound will never give us an upper bound.

Comment: @Greg Martin. As I wrote in my answer it's correct to understand $\frac{O(f)}{g} = O\left( \frac{f}{g}\right)$, though your example while generally is right, but for this case is useless: $\frac{O(x^6)}{x} = O\left( \frac{x^6}{x}\right) = O(x^5)$. On another hand we are discussing possible understandings of equation (1): I cannot speak in place of author(s) of source, but as I wrote in my answer possible(!) understanding is take function in de-numerator.

Answer (score -1):

For definition
$$O(g) =  \left\lbrace f:\exists C > 0, \exists U_\delta(x_0), \forall x \in U_\delta(x_0) \left(|f(x)| \leqslant C \cdot g(n) \right) \right\rbrace$$
is used notation $f(x)=O(g(x)), x\to x_0$ where under $x_0$ we understand also some $\infty$, respectively we understand neigbourhood for $x_0$. Obviously, mathematically correct record should be $f \in O(g)$, though often is used "$=$".

For simplicity let's consider positive functions. It's well known property of $O$, that for constant with respect to $x$ we can write
$$ C \cdot O(g) = O(C \cdot g) = O(g) $$
where all equalities we can understand as set equalities, i.e. holds in both directions.
Also it's well know properties
$$ O(f) \cdot O(g) = O(f \cdot g) $$
$$g \neq 0  \Rightarrow \dfrac{O(f)}{g} = O\left( \dfrac{f}{g}\right)$$

In your example, equation (1) $\dfrac{\mathscr{O}(h^{p+1})}{\mathscr{O}\left(\frac{h}{2}^{p+1}\right)}=\mathscr{O}\left(h\right)\tag{1}$ I see following possibility: if we have $\frac{h^{p+1}}{2}$ in place of $O\left( \left( \frac{h}{2} \right)^{p+1} \right)$ and, so, on right hand then you have $O(h) = O(1)$

But in this case you second equation is not true, because now you have both functions, so
$$\mathscr{O}\left(\frac{h}{2}^{p+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}^{p+1}\cdot\mathscr{O}\left(h^{p+1}\right) \ne \mathscr{O}\left(h^{p+1}\right)$$ .

Comment: As always, constructive critic is welcome.

Comment: @Greg Martin. Moral: do not down vote, if cannot discuss and argue.